# Laravel 4 - Handling 404s With Custom Messages

Tags: php, exception, error-handling, laravel, http-status-code-404

According to Laravel 4 [docs](http://laravel.com/docs/errors#http-exceptions) I can throw a 404 with a custom response:

```
App::abort(404, 'My Message');
```

I can then handle all of my 404s with a custom page:

```
App::missing(function($exception)
{
    return Response::view('errors.missing', array(), 404);
});
```

How can I pass 'My Message' through to the view in the same way that the generic Laravel error page does.

Thanks!

Comment: @totymedli I wanted to specify the message in the 'abort' function, rather than in the generic handler, so I can use multiple messages. I was just missing the `$exception->getMessage()` line. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can catch your message through the Exception parameter

```
App::missing(function($exception)
{
    $message = $exception->getMessage();
    $data = array('message', $message);
    return Response::view('errors.missing', $data, 404);
});
```

Note: The code can be reduced, I wrote it like this for the sake of clarity.

Comment: Exactly what I was after! Thanks very much.

Comment: In what file(s) and folder(s) do you have to add this code, @LukeJoyce ??

Comment: @pathros, if you are using Laravel 4.x this should be on `app.php`, I think it is similar for Laravel 5.

Answer (score 5):

In Laravel 5, you can provide Blade views for each response code in the `/resources/views/errors` directory. For example a 404 error will use `/resources/views/errors/404.blade.php`.

What's not mentioned in the manual is that inside the view you have access to the `$exception` object. So you can use `{{ $exception->getMessage() }}` to get the message you passed into `abort()`.

Comment: Can't be upvoted enough. I like Laravel, but it's "read the framework" approach to documentation can be a little frustrating.