# Pass a custom message (or any other data) to Laravel 404.blade.php

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5, and I have created a file `404.blade.php` in

```
views/errors/404.blade.php
```

This file gets rendered each time I call:

```
abort(404); // alias of App::abort(404);
```

How can I pass a custom message? Something like this in `404.blade.php`

```
Sorry, {{ $message }}
```

Filled by (example):

```
abort(404, 'My custom message');
```

or

```
abort(404, array(
    'message' => 'My custom message'
));
```

In Laravel 4 one could use `App::missing`:

```
App::missing(function($exception)
{
    $message = $exception->getMessage();
    $data = array('message', $message);
    return Response::view('errors.404', $data, 404);
});
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

(Note: copied from [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34111994/37947).)

In Laravel 5, you can provide Blade views for each response code in the `/resources/views/errors` directory. For example a 404 error will use `/resources/views/errors/404.blade.php`.

What's not mentioned in the manual is that inside the view you have access to the `$exception` object. So you can use `{{ $exception->getMessage() }}` to get the message you passed into `abort()`.

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat you just saved me, my man. The `{{ $exception->getMessage() }}` in Laravel 5.1 documentation isn't available. Hats of to you :)

Answer (score 7):

Extend Laravel's Exception Handler, `Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler`, and override `renderHttpException(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException $e)` method with your own.

If you haven't run `php artisan fresh`, it will be easy for you. Just edit `app/Exceptions/Handler.php`, or create a new file.

### Handler.php

```
<?php namespace App\Exceptions;

use Exception;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler as ExceptionHandler;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException;

class Handler extends ExceptionHandler {

  // ...

  protected function renderHttpException(HttpException $e) {
    $status = $e->getStatusCode();

    if (view()->exists("errors.{$status}")) {
      return response()->view("errors.{$status}", compact('e'), $status);
    }
    else {
      return (new SymfonyDisplayer(config('app.debug')))->createResponse($e);
    }
  }

}
```

And then, use `$e` variable in your `404.blade.php`.

i.e.

```
abort(404, 'Something not found');
```

and in your `404.blade.php`

```
{{ $e->getMessage() }}
```

For other useful methods like `getStatusCode()`, refer `Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception`

Answer (score 0):

How about sharing a variable globally?

```
 view()->share('message', 'llnk has gone away');
 // or using the facade
 View::share('message', 'llnk has gone away badly');
```

Just make sure in the template to fallback to a default in case you forget to set it.

See sharing data with views: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/views

Comment: That could be interesting (sorry cannot upvote i don't have much reputation), the problem is that you will need to call it each time you do an abort... Example: `view()->share('message', 'llnk has gone away'); abort(404);`

Comment: You can define one message globally `view()->share('404_message','foo');` and overrule it with the same method when required for specifics. Or even better just define a fallback (as said). Why else would  you need a variable if you don't want it to be variable in some cases? :)

Comment: If you'd like to use the second parameter (exception message) from the abort function in the template you can use the App::missing and simply assign the exception message to the template.

Comment: Can I get the Exception message inside 404.blade.php without passing from App::missing?

Comment: You could overrule the ErrorHandler and the method renderHttpException see: Illuminate\Foundation\Exception\Handler:106-124

Comment: is App::missing() available for Laravel 5? It seems it has been removed

Comment: Yep, my bad. You need to use App\Exceptions\Handler; see http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/errors