# Displaying exception error message in 404 pages

Tags: php, exception, laravel-5

I have a controller where i do something like this

```
return abort('401', 'User cannot be found');
```

**How do i access the message in my view (errors/401.blade.php).**

```
/************* 401.blade.php ***********/
{{ dd($exception) }}
```

**If i die dump $exception** in my view i get this

```
HttpException {#203 ▼
  -statusCode: "401"
  -headers: []
  #message: "User cannot be found"
  #code: 0
  #file: "C:\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php"
  #line: 882
  -trace: array:54 [▶]
}
```

How to do i access the message variable?

Comment: Well the controller code doesn't matter, it simply checks for a user in the database and if its not found it aborts. The controller is redirecting to the 401 page correctly, i just need to show the error message that i passed through the abort function inside the 401.blade.php

Comment: Did you tried using `try.. catch`

Comment: well i cant try catch after the abort statement, i just need to know how to access the HttpException (Headers) in the view. It should have been something as simple as {{ $exception->message }}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, in Laravel documentation said this:

> Custom HTTP Error Pages
>
> Laravel makes it easy to return custom error pages for various HTTP
>   status codes. For example, if you wish to customize the error page for
>   404 HTTP status codes, create a resources/views/errors/404.blade.php.
>   This file will be served on all 404 errors generated by your
>   application.
>
> **The views within this directory should be named to match the HTTP
>   status code they correspond to.**

I think you have to create a `401.blade.php` view and then your code will work.

As showed here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29633624/4425719

> Extend Laravel's Exception Handler,
>   `Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler`, and override
>   `renderHttpException(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException
>   $e)` method with your own.
>
> If you haven't run `php artisan fresh`, it will be easy for you. Just
>   edit `app/Exceptions/Handler.php`, or create a new file.
>
> ### Handler.php
>
> ```
> <?php namespace App\Exceptions;
>
> use Exception;
> use Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler as ExceptionHandler;
>
> use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException;
>
> class Handler extends ExceptionHandler {
>
>   // ...
>
>   protected function renderHttpException(HttpException $e) {
>     $status = $e->getStatusCode();
>
>     if (view()->exists("errors.{$status}")) {
>       return response()->view("errors.{$status}", compact('e'), $status);
>     }
>     else {
>       return (new SymfonyDisplayer(config('app.debug')))->createResponse($e);
>     }
>   }
>
> }
> ```
>
> And then, use `$e` variable in your `404.blade.php`.
>
> i.e.
>
> ```
> abort(404, 'Something not found');
> ```
>
> and in your `404.blade.php`
>
> ```
> {{ $e->getMessage() }}
> ```
>
> For other useful methods like `getStatusCode()`, refer
>   `Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception`

Comment: I already have a 401.blade.php file, (i have edited the answer) but it doesn't show the message passed through the abort function.

Comment: @omerFarooq I updated de answer with a solution i found in another stackoverflow question. You have to adapt it to 401 error code, but i think is the same thing.