# Laravel 5: Custom abort() message

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Using Laravel 5, I want to send a custom `abort()` message.
For example, if the user doesn't have the required permissions for an action,
I'd like to `abort(401, "User can't perform this actions")`.
Currently, when I do so, the response text is HTML page and not the message.
How can I return only the message?

**Note:** I don't want to pass a different view, but only the custom message.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass a custom message (or any other data) to Laravel 404.blade.php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29163564/pass-a-custom-message-or-any-other-data-to-laravel-404-blade-php)

Comment: This behavior was fixed in Laravel 5.5. It will give back a JSON-formatted error that includes your message automatically when you call `abort($code, $message)` (provided `$request->wantsJson()`).

Answer (score 37):

According to Laravel 5.4 documentation:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/errors#http-exceptions

You can use `abort` helper with response text:

```
abort(500, 'Something went wrong');
```

And use `$exception->getMessage()` in `resources/views/errors/500.blade.php` to display it:

```
Error message: {{ $exception->getMessage() }}
```

Comment: This would be the correct way to do this, but how would I add 'newline' character, or line break (or bullets even better) in this message?

Comment: @blamb If the message contains HTML code (like <br>), use {!! !!} syntax instead of {{ }} to display unescaped content.

Comment: in laravel 5.7  `@section('message', __( $exception->getMessage() ? $exception->getMessage() :'Whoops, something went wrong on our servers.'))`

Answer (score 19):

You can wrap a response inside abort, which will stop the execution and return the response. If you want it to be JSON then add `->json();`

```
# Regular response
abort( response('Unauthorized', 401) );

# JSON response 
abort( response()->json('Unauthorized', 401) );
```

Comment: Shorter if we use an array message `abort( response(['message' => 'Unauthorized'], 401) );` for JSON.

Answer (score 12):

The answer is simply to use the response() helper method instead of abort(). Syntax as below.

```
return response("User can't perform this action.", 401);
```

Comment: However, `return` would continue with the execution of the caller. With `abort`, I don't want carry on with any business logic.

Comment: Oh, and this doesn't work either, at least in my app it didn't. `response('', 400)->json('some message')` still returned HTML page.

Answer (score 1):

You can handle all error exceptions here app/Exceptions/Handler.php Class On your requirement.

In your case just replace render function with this

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
   return $e->getMessage();
   //For Json
   //return response()->json(['message' => $e->getMessage()]);
}
```

Comment: I tried it, but then it won't get to the .catch in the browser.

Comment: i didn't get you "it won't get to the .catch in the browser" means

Comment: Using Promise: promise.then(this._thenMethod).catch(this._defaultCatcher);

Comment: Okay. I'm not sure but try send response as json like this return response()->json(['message' => $e->getMessage()]);

Answer (score 1):

Should be able to use the following in the template:

```
{{ $exception->getMessage() }}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `Handler.php` I altered the function:

```
 public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
    $response = parent::render($request, $e);

    if (method_exists($e, "getStatusCode")) {
        if ($e->getStatusCode() == 401) {
            $response->setContent($e->getMessage());
        }
    }

    return $response;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I find this to be very clean if you are writing API's instead of using the default abort() exception error ):

```
 abort( response()->json(["message"=>"an error occur"], Response::HTTP_NOT_FOUND) );
```

Comment: not working with laravel 9

Comment: I am currently using it in Laravel 9 and it works. can you share what error you are getting when you tried it .

Comment: use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response;

Answer (score 0):

In `api.php` file, add this

```
 Route::fallback(function () {
  return abort(401,"User can't perform this action.");
 });
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all add the error message in your header file or in the page where you want to show the message like:

```
@if($errors->has())
    @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
        <div>{{ $error }}</div>
    @endforeach
@endif
```

And in the controller, you can do this kind of stuff (e.g.):

```
public function store(){
    if(user is not permitted to access this action) // check user permission here
    {
        return redirect()->back()->withErrors("User can't perform this actions");
    }
}
```

You can redirect back with error message

Comment: I should add that I'm talking about an $.ajax call and not browser redirect.